# Windows Host Docker + WSL - Volume mounting issue

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume

thx to corona - most of us working from home and due to some convenience, i want to use my windows machine that i have here at home.

I do run Win10 with DockerDesktop Version 2.3.0.3 with Engine running on Version 19.03.8.
What I am doing is exposing the docker deamon on localhost in order to use it from my WSL (Version 1, not 2) installed Ubuntu.
Docker itself works, I can pull images and do basic stuff. But I am facing issues when mounting volumes :-/

When I try to run my docker-compose up command, it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: for my-service  Cannot start service my-service: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/someDir/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /home/myUser/myLocalDirectory:/var/lib/docker/volumes/someDir/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
```

The directory `/home/myUser/myLocalDirectory` does exist.
Directory `/var/lib/docker/volumes/someDir/_data` does not exist on my WSL "host". There is only a `/var/lib/docker-engine/...` folder, which is obviously not the one i am looking for :-/

My working path is `/mnt/e/projects/myDockerProject` - but i also tried to mount/bind the folder/harddrive like shown [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1854#issuecomment-291845122).

All does not work and i am really stuck - do you have any suggestions/explanations?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem . As I am also stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 2):

When I run a linux container using Docker for Windows, I bind-mount `c:/the/windows/path:/desired/path/in/the/container`.

There's a lot of layers here:

```
         ___ WSL
        /
Windows
        \___ Docker Linux VM -- Containers
```

Under "normal" circumstances (linux host with linux containers), you bind mount a local directory.  In the diagram above, that would correspond to a directory in the Docker Linux VM.  But Docker for Windows allows us to specify a windows path instead.

When you throw WSL into the mix, things get a bit muddier. Within WSL, `/home` is already some kind of magic that isn't shown to be directly linked to the `c` drive:

```
root@MyPcName:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs         498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /
root           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /root
home           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /home
data           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /data
cache          498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /cache
mnt            498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /mnt
none           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /dev
none           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /run
none           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /run/lock
none           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /run/shm
none           498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /run/user
cgroup         498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /sys/fs/cgroup
C:\            498557588 390255608 108301980  79% /mnt/c
```

`/home` obviously corresponds to `C:\Users`, but you can't tell from the output of `df` or the contents of `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/fstab`.

I would suggest that you try the following:

1. Specify the windows path: `C:/Users/myUser/myLocalDirectory:/desired/path/in/the/container`
2. Specify the WSL path starting with the "base" windows drive - note the double slashes on WSL side: `//mnt/c/Users/myUser/myLocalDirectory:/desired/path/in/the/container`
3. If neither of those work, launch `docker-compose up` from a DOS or powershell prompt, and use the windows path as in #1 above

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue:

```
[+] Running 0/1
⠹ Container mysqllocal  Creating                    0.2s
Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount
/run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/0728c21eeaba2a2ed809c50fb993ad2a7f00d011276b110991eafe61e99bbd25:/var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql-volume/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
```

In my case after the `docker volume prune` the `docker volume ls` shows no volumes but the docker desktop interface still have volumes listed.

The issue was fixed after removing the volumes using the docker desktop interface.